# Listing all capabilities in dropdown is returning boolean

Tags: capabilities, php, select

Trying to put a list of all possible caps in a dropdown. I can only get it to return 1s (boolean true). If I use var_dump($user->allcaps); it does produce the actual cap names, but when I plug this into my function, it goes to boolean. Have tried using various settype statements; nothing has worked. Here's the function currently:

```
add_shortcode('capsdropdown', 'sc_capsdropdown');
function sc_capsdropdown($attr) {
$user = get_user_by('id', '1');
$capslist = $user->allcaps;
$dropdown = '<select>';
foreach($capslist as $cap){
$dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>';
}
$dropdown .= '</select>';
return $dropdown;
}
```

Resolved. This works:

```
foreach($capslist as $cap=>$caps){ $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>'; }
```

Comment: Resolved. This works:

foreach($capslist as $cap=>$caps){ $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>'; }

Comment: Hi, Thom, please [read the etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) regarding multi-posts and add your solution as an Answer, so this Question doesn't remain on the *unanswered* list, thanks!

Comment: I tried to answer it but it told me to come back in six hours. So I had planned to do so.

Comment: brasofilo, thanks for the link to the etiquette. I apologize for that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19193519) at Stack Overflow.

> Each Array Key was the actual name of the capability [...] You were searching for the capabilities by name, and since you were only seeing 1s in the output, I figured what you were looking for was in the keys.

```
foreach($capslist as $cap=>$caps){ 
    $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>'; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain _why_ that works, so future visitors with a similar problem understand the solution?